# Baldur's Gate 3 how to convert wav to wem correctly so that these files work in the game's voice acting?

Tags: wav, modgrammar

Question: How can I correctly convert `wav` files to `wem` format for Baldur's Gate 3 to make these files work in the game's voiceover?

1. I use `ExportTool-v1.18.5` to extract the contents of `Voice.pak` and `English.pak` files.
2. Then, I search for the desired dialogue in the file `C:\UnpackedData\English\Localization\English\english.xml` and note down the `contentuid` from the line.
3. I search for the audio track using the `contentuid` in the `C:\UnpackedData\Voice` folder.
4. For example, I find the file `v2c76687d93a2477b8b188a14b549304c_hcb228250g01eeg4e3cg88abg3f55fb87ee71.wem`.
5. I convert the file `v2c76687d93a2477b8b188a14b549304c_hcb228250g01eeg4e3cg88abg3f55fb87ee71.wem` to the `wav` format using `vgmstream` to ensure that I have found the correct audio track.
6. I synthesize a new audio recording in the `wav` format.
7. Then, I attempt to convert the `wav` file to the `wem` format through `Wwise`. The conversion is successful, and even `vgmstream` can play the converted `wav` correctly. However, in the game, the audio track doesn't play and there is silence.
8. I replace the original `wem` audio track with the synthesized `wem` audio track.
9. Using `ExportTool-v1.18.5`, I compile a new `pak` file, ensuring to select `No compression` and `Solid`.
10. Then, I test the changes in the game's voiceover by launching the game. Currently, the method of replacing the original `wem` files with a copy of the original audio track works, where I give the copied track the same name to ensure that the compilation process is correct. This way, the audio track in the game is modified. However, if I attempt to synthesize a new audio track and convert it to the `wem` format, there is silence during the dialogue in the game.

Comment: NexusMods.com might give better answers.  The game might be checking for tampering or damaged data, or it could be something else like the bit rate or bits per sample might be wrong

Comment: To test this theory, I replaced the original audio track with another original audio track that had a different length and a different tone, but the file name remained the same. This approach worked. I believe that the issue lies specifically in converting way to wem as there are likely different programs for this conversion.

Comment: So not the length, but the WEM format - metadata / header, bit rate or bits sample, or some other difference

Comment: A hex editor like HexEd might help you compare headers, then try different conversion programs to see if one matches the existing files better.  Once you figure this out you might post to NexusMods forums to help other modders, and add an answer to your own question here.

Comment: The original audio track in wav format has a bit rate of 768 kbps, while the synthesized audio track in wav format has a bit rate of 384 kbps.

Comment: You could also try re-encoding the existing WEM (from the WAV version) with your encoder to see if the re-encoded WEM  works.  If that works for the existing WAV but not new ones then the bit rate does seem likely and maybe you can upsample the synth voice? If re-encoding the original voice fails, then try the original voice using a different encoder

Comment: I am stuck at the same point, as you. Have you made any advancements that suggest another line of research to solve this question?

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, I ran into this same problem while researching Shadow of the Tomb Raider and found that the problem lies in the .bnk files (Wwise SoundBanks). Normally, a sound is either fully embedded in the SoundBank or stored separately as a .wem file. However, something inbetween is apparently also possible: the full sound is stored as a .wem file, and the first part of the sound is *also* embedded in the .bnk file. I'm guessing this is a latency countermeasure: giving the game some data to play while it prepares to stream the external .wem.

In any case, if the .bnk contains (say) the first 300 bytes of the sound, the game will *skip* the first 300 bytes of the .wem file. You could zero out the whole header of the original .wem and it would still play. But if you replace the .wem by a custom one, it'll no longer match up with the prefetch data in the .bnk and refuse to play.

The solution is to remove this prefetch data from the .bnk. You can use this template for 010 Editor to do that: https://github.com/eXpl0it3r/bnkextr/blob/master/bnk.bt

You'll want to:

- Open the .bnk
- Apply the template
- Expand the "didx" (Data Index) section
- Find the entry with id = the ID of your .wem file
- Change the "length" field to 0.

...That being said, Wwise sounds use 32-bit numbers as their IDs, which are nothing like the long contentuids from your post. So you'd have to find the mapping somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

check your initial .wem with command (for example):

```
vgmstream-cli.exe 103010647.wem
```

it will show format .wem decoded:

```
 decoding 103010647.wem
sample rate: 48000 Hz
channels: 1
channel mask: 0x4 / FC
stream total samples: 82148 (0:01.711 seconds)
encoding: Custom Vorbis
layout: flat
metadata from: Audiokinetic Wwise RIFF header
bitrate: 76 kbps
play duration: 82148 samples (0:01.711 seconds)
```

but if you encode .waves to .wems with wwise "as is" it will encode like:

```
decoding 103010647.wem_818F3B66.wem
sample rate: 48000 Hz
channels: 1
channel mask: 0x4 / FC
stream total samples: 82148 (0:01.711 seconds)
encoding: Little Endian 16-bit PCM
layout: flat
metadata from: Audiokinetic Wwise RIFF header
bitrate: 768 kbps
play duration: 82148 samples (0:01.711 seconds)
```

so you need to change in wwise conversion format with bitrate closer to yours initial .wem:
default work unit - click on one of imported files -> conversion -> defauilt conversion settings -> choose format and choose bitrate in Adv.

after that as usual in wwise -> convert all files